# Does Pact support REST and JMS?

Tags: pact

I want to start using the framework Pact for JVM for contract testing. But does Pact JVM support REST and JMS?

I haven't found any information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Pact JVM](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm) supports REST[1], its primary use case, and also supports JMS testing in the form of *Messages* [2].

Note that as of this moment, the other language implementations don't support this *Message* style test, but the work is in progress to make it happen.

- [1] Assuming REST = JSON/HTTP
- [2] https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-consumer-junit#consumer-test-for-a-message-consumer

Comment: Thx for answer! It seems that I have one more answer on my question, could you help me sort it out :)?

Answer (score 0):

Pact is a restful consumer/provider testing tool only; It has to communicate over HTTP and the data contract can only be in JSON at the moment (this could change in the future).  We have talked about supporting other protocols like messaging (websockets), but there isn't much need for it as of yet and we have other priorities to work on currently.

Comment: Thx for answer! It seems that I have one more answer on my question, could you help me sort it out :)?